# Starting a Windows application from a Flex4 mxml desktop application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I want to write a Flex4 mxml application which can be used to start a Windows application like Skype/Word on the click of a button. How to do this using Flash Builder 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe AIR runtime can do this and I could launch notepad/skype from a flex application

Answer (score 1):

it is only available in AIR (desktop) applications lookup NativeProcess and embed native C code to do the task compiled once for each OS

Answer (score 0):

Flash player cannot launch external applications as it would be a serious security threat.
(How about downloading and launching stealCreditCardInfo.exe?)

Comment: but can't you make a desktop application in Flex4?

Comment: You can build a desktop application with Flex/AIR, but you can't launch external applications in that application.

Answer (score 0):

The Flex SDK doesn't support this. Also with AIR you can't do this.

Mike Chambers has posted o [proof of concept article](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/) which could help you.